# Set headers for scrapy shell request

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I know that you can `scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='custom user agent' 'http://www.example.com'` to change the `USER_AGENT`, but how do you add request headers?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

there is no current way to add headers directly on cli, but you could do something like:

```
$ scrapy shell
...
...
>>> from scrapy import Request
>>> req = Request('yoururl.com', headers={"header1":"value1"})
>>> fetch(req)
```

This will update the current shell information with that new request.