# scrapy shell and scrapyrt got 403 but scrapy crawl works

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping a website which requires `referer`.

I set it like this.

```
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'Referer': 'http://www.referer.com'
}
```

When I tried `scrapy shell url` in the project folder (the one has `scrapy.cfg`), which means it's using the same settings in the `settings.py` file, I can see the `referer` is in the request, but I got a `403` response.

> [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) https://my_url.com (referer: http://www.referer.com)

However, without changing any thing, `scrapy crawl my_spider` has no issue.

> [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to https://redirected_my_url.com> from https://my_url.com>

I'm also `scrapyrt`, which has the same issue as `scrapy shell`.

Comment: Use a `user-agent` and I hope it will work

Comment: @Umair I used `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36`, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check the robots.txt of your website. Sometimes, it doesn't exist.
If the robots.txt allows the robots, then it is unlikely the issue is from it. Else, you write `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in settings.py or in the command `scrapy crawl or shell -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`. As you wish.

About user agent. For user agent, in scrapy shell one is enough as far as I know, for a crawling spider it is better to create a list of bunch of user agent and to make it random.

If this is not enough.
Finally, use `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3`, with a value at least 1 in your settings.py or command. To make your spider, in crawl or shell, acting more like a conventional browser. You can use too `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True` , for the same reason:

```
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 1
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
```