# How to crawl links which returns 403 error using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** course details from udemy, but it returns error as 403. I tried using user-agents but still it does'nt work.

```
import scrapy


class UdemySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'udemy'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/search-courses/recommendation/?course_badge=beginners_choice&page_size=5&skip_price=true&q=python'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    data = response.json()
    yield data
```

I have used [scrapy-user-agent](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-user-agents/) but still unable to scrape the data.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202058/how-to-solve-403-error-in-scrapy/39202689, you basically just put headers into a `Request` object

Comment: Why does it return 403? Do you need to log in to see the courses? Have you tried that?

Comment: I can see the courses even without logging into it. I agree with the answer of @A.K.M.Adib and will look into it