# unable to create url with headers to simulate an XHR request?

Tags: python, http, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

I want to scrape [this link](https://jadopado.com/en-sa/mobile-phones/c/4298?filter=&page=1&sorting=-launchedAt) using scrapy. The link in browser is referring to another http [request](https://api.jadopado.com/v1/categories/4298/products?page=1&sort=-launchedAt&recordsPerPage=40&showPagination=true). Accessing this referred call in browser directly returns:  *{"message": "Invalid or expired token"}*.
Following the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010524/set-headers-for-scrapy-shell-request) I did:

```
scrapy shell
headers= {'X-JadoPado-API-Token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHAiOiJqYWRvcGFkby5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGwsImV4cCI6MTQ5NDMzMjE0OSwia2lkIjoiYWQxNWY3N2I0NzlmNDIxOTk0OGI5Y2U3MzMyOTQ2MzciLCJkZXZpY2UiOiI3YTc4YzM4Mi01N2VhLTQ3YjItODBiNi1lZTUzYjQ4MzhjNjAifQ.DWrdaIsFCTSAvfk2DEUrdxeloCSNArEk1zDncKlFz0M'}
req = Request("https://jadopado.com/en-sa/mobile-phones/c/4298?filter=&page=2&sorting=-launchedAt", headers=headers)
fetch(req)
```

I also tried doing the same thing setting all headers 
[image: request headers]

```
 headers = 
     {'Accept':'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Host':'api.jadopado.com',
    'Origin':'https://jadopado.com',
    'Referer':'https://jadopado.com/en-sa/mobile-phones/c/4298?filter=&page=2&sorting=-launchedAt',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
    'X-JadoPado-API-Token':'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHAiOiJqYWRvcGFkby5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGwsImV4cCI6MTQ5NDMzMjE0OSwia2lkIjoiYWQxNWY3N2I0NzlmNDIxOTk0OGI5Y2U3MzMyOTQ2MzciLCJkZXZpY2UiOiI3YTc4YzM4Mi01N2VhLTQ3YjItODBiNi1lZTUzYjQ4MzhjNjAifQ.DWrdaIsFCTSAvfk2DEUrdxeloCSNArEk1zDncKlFz0M',
    'X-JadoPado-Currency':'SAR',
    'X-JadoPado-Locale':'en',
    }
```

Even this did not work. Am I missing anything or is there a better way to scrape [link](https://jadopado.com/en-sa/mobile-phones/c/4298?filter=&page=1&sorting=-launchedAt) with scrapy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using correct `headers` but not the correct URL.

See `Request URL`

[image]

Try this code.

```
headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://jadopado.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'X-JadoPado-Locale': 'en',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
    'X-JadoPado-Currency': 'SAR',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://jadopado.com/en-sa/mobile-phones/c/4298?filter=&page=1&sorting=-launchedAt',
    'X-JadoPado-API-Token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHAiOiJqYWRvcGFkby5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGwsImV4cCI6MTQ5NDMzNTAzOSwia2lkIjoiYWMxOWM0YTFlY2FhNDA2MGE5ZjEwYjE1ZGQ3ZmUzZjMiLCJkZXZpY2UiOiJhNDQ4YWFmOS0zMDI0LTQ1NGQtOTg0MC0zYzMxZGI1YzcwMDcifQ.2m2VQ13owO0kLy8shcLuzuAPE8iNEsPEA0p4x640K8o',
}



yield Request('https://api.jadopado.com/v1/categories/?parentId=4298&page=1&recordsPerPage=500&showFee=true', headers=headers)
```

Comment: thanks as you pointed out request URL should be used instead of   referred url.